# Чи варто вживати літературну вимову? (Звук «ШЧ» та нескладове «У»)

Tags: фонетика

Я виріс в Канаді в переважно Російськомовній сім‘ї і тільки недавно почав серйозно вчити рідну мову.

Є кілька правил в літературній мові, яких рідко чую в звичайних розмовах: вимовлення літери «Щ» як два окремі звуки і особливо правило вимовлення літери «В» в деяких випадках як у нескладове (ў), яке я тільки чую в західних говорах і старих записах як наприклад: https://youtu.be/DGArUxiSFBc.

Я помічаю, що часто люди тільки вимовляють цей звук на кінці слів і лише в деяких словах як наприклад «вовк».

Я розумію, що існують багато діалектів в Україні, але мені цікаво, чи є вагома причина таких і подібних правил дотримуватись у повсякденному мовленні? Чи краще так для мене вимовляти чи залишити такі нюанси для журналістів та інших.

Іще, хтось може будь ласка мені пояснити, у яких випадках вимовляти у нескладове? Принципи я знаю, але не завжди впевнений: «під впливом».

Чи вимовляється перша літера другого слова як у нескладове? Здається мені що після приголосного в кінці попереднього слова важко вимовляти тут «в» більш як «у».

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до Ukrainian Language.SE! Цей допис містить багато запитань одночасно, а наші правила передбачають одне запитання на допис. Окрім того, запитання «чи варто?» явно запрошують до суб'єктивних думок (opinion-based), на відміну від фактів та свідчень (facts and evidence). Треба дуже ретельно формулювати такі запитання, інакше вони будуть закриті як primarily-opinion-based. Див. [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) та [Хороші питання і хороші відповіді](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/8)

Comment: (1) Щодо «під впливом», то Ви маєте на увазі, що його простіше вимовляти як «під упливом» (тобто повноцінне «у» замість «ў»)? Чи навпаки — що замість «ў» чи «у» Вам простіше вимовити там приголосний «в»? (2) Щодо «щ» — теж запитання: а як інакше Ви пропонуєте його вимовляти — як «ш»? Можливо, «ч» у «щ (шч)» не таке чітке, як в «ч», що стоїть окремо, тобто я б не наголошував на тому, що це два окремі звуки (воно вимовляється досить швидко), але все-таки і «ш», і «ч», мені здається, там однозначно [чути](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUrx793sn2I&t=1h30m39s).

Comment: @Sasha (1) на скільки я знаю то «ў» вимовляється якось так як і «w» в Англійській мові але не зовсім. Мені легше вимовляти як «в» або чітко як «у» замість щось між ними коли попереднє слово закінчується з приголосним. Після приголосного воно по суті виходить у мене як «у». Складно це пояснити і я не чув щоб люди так розмовляли крім випадків коли «ў» у кінці слова, наприклад «ходив». (2) я розумію що є такий звук звичайно, просто в житті частіше чую «ш» або «щ» і хотів знати чи може краще вимовляти як є у стандартній мові. Розумію що це напевно більш суб‘єктивне питання (вибачте @bytebuster)

Comment: @Sasha Мав на увазі звук «шь» а не «щ» в перед останньому реченні

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy, «після приголосного воно по суті виходить у мене як „у“» — наскільки я знаю, воно _так і має виходити_. Навіть згідно з [правилами милозвучності](https://pravopys.net/#search=11) так рекомендується не лише говорити, а й писати: між приголосними пишемо «у», а «в» пишемо між голосними або між голосною й приголосною. (Єдиний виняток — це поодинокі слова, значення яких змінюється залежно від початкового «в»/«у», наприклад, «уклад»/«вклад», я не знаю, чи можна, наприклад, «під вкладом» вимовляти як «під укладом», але, мені здається, таке розрізнення — це вже дещо проти традицій.)

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy, зазначу, що насправді в частини населення (особливо на півдні й сході) «в» перед грухими й на кінці слів перетворюється не в «ў», а в «ф» (як у росіян). Хоча це вважається неправильним, але маємо те, що маємо: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_phonology#Deviations_of_spoken_language.

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy, щодо «щ» як «шшь», то хоч вікіпедія і пише, що таке теж трапляється, але навіть для мене (я живу в Києві, тобто значною мірою серед російськомовного й суржикомовного населення) це звучить дивно. Тим більше, що «щ» часто йде перед голосними «а/и/о/у», тобто зовсім не пом'якшується, і хоч, може, у ньому й не на 100% повне «ч», але як там можна вставити «шшь» (тобто Ви маєте на увазі вимовляти так: «шшястя, Київшшіна, шшьо, шшюка»?), мені важко уявити. (Може, перед «і» «щ» й буде ближчим до «шшь», але навіть «гуляші́» й «гуля́щі», «пиші́ть» і «пищі́ть» звучать неоднаково.)

Comment: @Sasha я говорю більше про випадки з одиницею «що» ніж з іншими словами. Чесно кажучи я не бував в Україні багато разів і не виїжджав з центральної частини, але дивлячись деякі новини і інтерв’ю по телеканалам в Youtube, я часто чую що деякі телеведучі гості вимовляють «щ» у «що» з Російським акцентом (тобто шьо). В повсякденній розмові частіше чую «шо» (родина з селах Кіровоградщини та Черкащини) і практично тільки по телебаченню чую на каналах новин телеведучих які вимовляють як «шчо». Напевно через те що мало буваю в Україні я не знаю як переважно люди вимовляють «що».

Comment: @Sasha я питаю тому що напевно я просто звик вимовляти «що» як «шо» і цікаво мені як люди в Україні насправді розмовляють. Трохи важко мені перейти на правильну вимову тому що ця одиниця так часто виникає в розмові. Наприклад сказати «ще щось чи що?» з літературною вимовою для мене звучить трохи дивно як ніби щось з польської мови. Проте, слово як наприклад «щодо» або «батьківщина» я завжди вимовляю з звуком «шч» і в цих випадках мені дивно б звучало «шодо». Я розумію що це мабуть суб‘єктивне питання але чи вважаєте ви що краще дотримуватися стандартні правила вимови?

Comment: @Sasha Чи може літературний стандарт більше для тих хто працює в особливій професії (вчителі, ведучі по новинам, політики). Якби я почав строго вимовляти «шч» і «ў» коли спілкуюся з людьми то як б вони дивились на мене? Мені здається що так звучить на подобу якоїсь старо-української мови чи селянина з заходу країни 100 років тому. Не чую щоб люди сьогодні так говорили принаймні в містах. Вибачте, якось багатослівно вийшло і чіткого питання нема. Наступного разу якесь більш конкретне питання задам. Дякую!

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy добрий день. Що цікаво: ваші питання не завжди про саму мову. Чому ви думаєте, що ваше мовлення має керуватися чимось? Говоріть так, як вам подобається. Мова реґламентується лише в певних колах: на телебаченні, в уряді, у школі, в університеті, в суді тощо. Щодо вашого особистого спілкування найкраща порада - це спілкуватися так, як вам найбільше подобається і найприємніше. Якщо ж вам знадобиться офіційна українська мова для офіційного спілкування - це інша справа. Тоді є чіткі правила вимови, якщо хочете виглядати якнайбільш "поважно".

Comment: @P.Vowk і Sasha, вчергове звертаю вашу увагу на те, що коментарі існують лише з метою покращення самого допису (запитання). Усе інше, особливо ваші — цілком слушні — зауваження щодо можливої відповіді на запитання, **є оффтопіком** на цьому сайті і в усій мережі Stack Exchange. **Не узурпуймо** можливість відповісти на це запитання користувачам, які мають змогу та бажання написати повноцінні відповіді. **Пропоную** видалити цю стіну (напів-)відповідей у коментарях і зосередитися на порятунку запитання. Порятунку, бо запитання *Needs more focus* і може бути закритим, якщо не буде відредаговано.

Comment: @bytebuster можете закрити, не бачу сенс це питання вже змінювати. Я отримав інформацію і думки які шукав, дякую тим хто відповів. Постараюся наступного разу більш об‘єктивне і чітке питання задати

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy, ну, «що» як «шо» («щоб» як «шоб») — це, мені здається, дещо інше. Це суто розмовне (не для офіційно-ділового стилю) спрощення частовживаного слова (моживо, якось так раніше _къто_ перетворилося на _хто_, і колись _шо_ теж стане новою нормою). Але не «шьо» (мені здається).

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy, моя особиста суб'єктивна думка: (а) «в» як «v»/«f» (замість «β̞»/«ʋ»/«w»/«u̯»/«ʍ») — можливо (хоча це вважається неправильним, але деякі люди так кажуть); (б) «щ» як «ш» в _деяких_ частовживаних словах — майже розмовна норма; (в) але м'яке «щ» (так само як і м'яке «ч») — аж ніяк. (Проте зазначу, що я зустрічав, принаймні у фейсбуці, людей з повністю протилежними поглядами: і тих, хто просуває м'які «щ»/«ч», мовляв, це діалектна норма; і тих, для кого «v»/«f» — це російська чи суржик, але не варіант розмовної української).

Comment: @bytebuster я погоджуюсь із вами щодо того, що це не завжди і не зовсім питання, на яке може бути відповідь, і свої арґументи написав у коментарі. Я хотів перевести все у чат, але Ілля Рачковський не зможе там брати участь в обговоренні, адже для цього потрібно мати більше "репутації". Якби в Іллі було 20 репутації, ми би вже спокійно обговорювали все в чаті без обмежень.

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy дуже заохочую вас далі ставити питання, відповіді на які вас цікавлять. Щойно матимете 20 репутації - я зможу створити чат, де зможу детальніше пояснити правила спільноти. Їх не так складно дотримуватися, і вони навіть часто допомагають самостійно знайти відповіді.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"*Щ*"** завжди **вимовляється як "*шч*"** у тому числі в розмовній мові (окрім як у словах "*що*", "*ще*" та похідних). Також, як російськомовному, пропоную зауважити **твердість *ч***. Вимова накшталт *щьо*, *чьоботи* звучить смішно і ріже вухо.  *Щ* в принципі неможливо вимовити як один звук, якщо у ньому вимовляти тверде *ч*, а не м'яке (російське) *чь*.

Слова *що*, *ще* та їхні похідні у розмовній мові дуже часто вимовляються **зі звуком *ш***, проте це **є нелітературним** і вважається ознакою неосвіченої мови.

---

*Нескладове ў* - звук повністю аналогічний англійському *w* та польскому *ł*. Мати його ідеальну вимову не є обов'язковим, але варто зауважити, що в українській мові ***в* ніколи не оглушується до *ф*** як це відбувається у російській.

> Я помічаю, що часто люди тільки вимовляють цей звук на кінці слів і лише в деяких словах як наприклад «вовк».

Так, багато де існує тенденція до заміни *ў* перед приголосними на *в* або навіть *ф*, але це не є літературним.

> Іще, хтось може будь ласка мені пояснити, у яких випадках вимовляти у нескладове? Принципи я знаю, але не завжди впевнений: «під впливом».

Оскільки вимовити чотири голосних *-двпл-* дійсно важко, то нескладове *ў* перетворюється в звичайне складове *у* і словосполучення звучить як "*під **у**пливом*", створюючи ше один склад. Власне так воно і має писатися (чергування у-в).

---

Як підсумок:

> чи є вагома причина таких і подібних правил дотримуватись у повсякденному мовленні? Чи краще так для мене вимовляти чи залишити такі нюанси для журналістів та інших.

Звичайно, що при можливості найкраще вчити саме літературну вимову, проте в першу чергу я все ж рекомендував би звернути увагу на наступні пункти:

- у літері *щ* звук *ч* має бути твердим
- *в* ніколи не оглушується до *ф*
- нескладове *ў* може перетворюватися у звичайне складове перед приголосними (явище "чергування у-в"), що не завжди відображається на письмі.

---

Ось можна почитати загалом про нескладові голосні в українській:
https://zbruc.eu/node/41905

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Скажіть, будь ласка, чи існує офіційне джерело літературних правил, чи ці правила походять з безлічі різних джерел?

Comment: @IllyaRachkovskyy наскільки мені відомо, то єдиного офіційно затвердженого джерела накшталт правопису не існує. Натомість, є велика кількість робіт і літератури з фонетики, фонології та орфоепії української мови. Власне, у "літературній вимові" (як сукупності рекомендацій) є загальноприйняті речі (як згадані мною у відповіді), а є й дещо спірні. Наприклад, рівень закритості ненаголошених "е" та "о".

Answer (score 0):

"чи існує офіційне джерело літературних правил"
Офіційне джерело — Атлас Української Мови. Подивіться: ніде нема шьо. Тілки шо й шчо.
P.S. І сумно й смішно читать відповіді "знавців"

Олекса Синявський
https://studfile.net/preview/2269711/page:2/

Answer (score -1):

Пане те що ви помітили, це нормальна частина української мови.

В давньоруській ч було саме м'яким. І це не ексклюзивний винахід російської мови.
в багатьох джерелах зустрічаються паралельні форми,поряд з ѥ, ѧ, ю після ч писали також є, а, у. Наприклад, чѧдо—чадо [t͡ɕadɔ], чюдити—чудити [t͡ɕudɪtɪ]

звук ў теж є у ряді діалектів, особливо поліських, вони там мають ряд  рис спільних для української та білоруської мов

В канаду емігрували в основному з західних терен. Тому в канадійському варіянті української багато саме рис південно-західного наріча, де ч саме м'яке.

Стосовно правил беріть приклад з англійської де базіліон різних варіантів та норм. хтось говорить амерікан інгліш, хтось британською. А самі брити тролять один одного що різні діалекти на островах нерозумілі між собою.

Україська літературна мова = це урізана лінгва франка, в першу чергу для потреб держави: освіти, телебачення,  радіо, міжрегіонального спілкування.

Виробляйте свій стиль, і спілкуйтесь як вам подобається.
ніхто в побуті не говорить літературною, та і воно нінада.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: За звук [ў] написали неточно. Звук [u̯~w], як алофон /в/, питомий для всіх українських говорів, не лише північних. Він уже був щонайменше в давньоруській мові, а скоріше й навіть у праслов'янській до певної міри, бо *v первісно було губно-губним/двогубним звуком, а для питомих мовців української й далі лишається двогубним. Окрім того, [u̯~w] походить не лише з *v, а й *l у сполуці *CъlC (*vъlkъ – "вовк"). Цей перехід присутній у всіх говорах, і, ясна річ, звук [ɫ] перейшов до [u̯~w], не [v] (між [ɫ] та [v] артикуляційно величезна різниця).